# Find field that was changed

Tags: sql-server

I have database with log backup every 15 minutes.

I believe some data in one table was changed 10 hours ago.

Is there any way I can find that query and located changed/updated data in log backup file?
If not is there any other way?

TNX!

Answer (score 2):

SQL Server doesn't log the query text of an update. You can find the log records using 3rd party log reader tools (or [`fn_dblog`](http://rusanu.com/2014/03/10/how-to-read-and-interpret-the-sql-server-log/)), and you may be able to find out who did it (depends on authentication mode and how your users log in), and you can find the previous version of the data by restoring to a point in time before the update, but you're not going to be able to find the query after the fact.

It may be time to start taking away rights, adding auditing (the full-blown auditing feature or your own triggers), or forcing data manipulation through stored procedures and rolling your own logging.

Comment: TNX. I think so..that only way is to restore database to some point and then compare data.
Do you have any experience in Change Data Capture. Is that solution to be able to see data change.

Comment: CDC captures changes but I won't it will tell you who or what query they issued. You also can't turn it on now to see changes that already happened, and it can't be used to compare two copies of a database - look at SQL Data Compare from Red Gate or similar tools for that.

Answer (score 0):

You would need to load the backups into another server and then iteratively load the transaction logs and compare.

Comment: Tnx..I was actually afraid that restore data is only option I have. I was hoping there is way to read log backup file :/